# Create tail from linux with C

Tags: c

I have to make the tail function from linux to display the last n lines of a file. It should be ran as example: ./a.out fileToRead.txt 3, where 3 is the number of lines to display. Right now my program reads a new line, then moves the last 3 lines one spot back in the array and then puts the newly read line on the last place.

```
#define MAXLEN 11

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE* in=fopen(argv[1],"rt");
    int n=atoi(argv[2]);
    char** ending=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        ending[i]=malloc(MAXLEN*sizeof(char));
    }
    char* line=malloc(MAXLEN*sizeof(char));

    do
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            ending[i]=ending[i+1];
        }
        ending[n-1]=line;
    } while (fgets(line,MAXLEN,in));
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s",ending[i]);
    }
    fclose(in);
    free(line);
    free(ending);
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns only the last line 3 times instead of the last 3 lines. From what I can guess the problem is the statement in the first for loop, but the way it is now makes sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for your `n` lines. You only allocate memory for `n` pointers to memory that might hold a line but you leave them unitialized, pointing to "random" addresses. Then you assign the address of `line` which points to one single buffer and after a while all your pointers in the array point to the same buffer. To store multiple different lines, you must alloate multiple buffers and copy the content instead of assigning the address of input buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a possible fix, as mention by Gerhardh comment you need to allocate new memory for each new ending-line other wise you are just reusing it and therefore reassigning it to the last value

```c
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /*
    make sure you check that argv 1 and 2 are not empty
    and make sure you handel File open/read exceptions
    */
    FILE* in=fopen(argv[1],"rt");
    int n=atoi(argv[2]);
    char** ending=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        ending[i]=malloc(MAXLEN*sizeof(char));
    }
    char* line = malloc(MAXLEN*sizeof(char));
    
    while (fgets(line,MAXLEN,in));
    {   
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            ending[i]=ending[i+1];
        }
        ending[n-1]=line;
        //need to allocate new memory for new endingline
        line = malloc(MAXLEN*sizeof(char));
    } 
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s",ending[i]);
    }
    
    fclose(in);

    //make sure you free corrently all allocated memory
    free(line);
    free(ending);
    
    //you should return value depending if you succeded or not (variable)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you might have a memory leak. You free `ending` but not the pointers that each element of `ending` point to.

Comment: good catch, as the code itself shows, the original code is far from being end code. I usually leave part of the cleanup to the OP based on my comments. the loop part is  the only thing I fixed, any issue with other parts of the code are still there.